# Recovering Kafka Data from .log Files

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 1-node kafka that crashed recently. I was able to salvage the .log and .index files from `/tmp/kafka-logs/mytopic-0/` and I have moved these files to a different server and installed kafka on it.

Is there a way to have the new kafka server serve the data contained in these .log files?

**Update:**

I probably didn't do this the right way, but here is what I've tired:

1. created a topic named *recovermytopic* on the new kafka server
   stopped kafka
2. moved all the .log files into `/tmp/kafka-logs/recovermytopic-0`
3. restarted kafka
4. it appeared that for each .log file, kafka generated a .index file, looked promising but after the index files were created, I saw messeages below:

   ```
   WARN Partition [recovermytopic,0] on broker 0: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [recovermytopic,0] (kafka.cluster.Partition)  
   INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [recovermytopic,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
   ```

When I try to check the topic using kafka-console-consumer, the kafka server says:

```
INFO Closing socket connection to /127.0.0.1. (kafka.network.Processor)
```

no messages being consumed..

Comment: what do you mean by requeue?

Comment: @nautilus having the new instance of kafka serve the messages in the log files. rephrased the question, thanks!

Comment: try creating a topic with the same name and the same number of partitions. The consumers to consume information from the beginning can be reseted using OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST

Comment: @nautilus thanks, just tried, on the consumer's side, I get this error: `Failed to find leader for Set([mytopic,0])`

Comment: that happens when you create the consumer? what version are you using? the broker and zookeeper have started correctly?

Comment: @nautilus I'm using `kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer ` to test. Zookeeper gets started correctly,  when broker starts, it throws `kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0` a couple of times, everything (new leader, broker registered) is normal after that, but when I try to consume the topic with kafka-console-consumer.sh, I see the "closing socket connection" message again. :-/

Comment: @nautilus thanks for the quick reply, when I try to create a topic with 0 replication factor, the server says `kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor must be larger than 0`

Comment: I am sorry, you are right! somehow the broker is down at that point, the log doesn't say anything before that?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka comes packaged with a `DumpLogSegments` tool that will extract messages (along with offsets, etc.) from Kafka data log files:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --deep-iteration --print-data-log --files mytopic-0/00000000000000132285.log > 00000000000000132285_messages.out
```

The output will vary a bit depending on which version of Kafka you're using, but it should be easy to extract the message keys and values with the use of `sed` or some other tool. The messages can then be replayed into your Kafka cluster using the `kafka-console-producer.sh` tool, or programmatically.

While this method is a bit roundabout, I think it's more transparent/reliable than trying to get a broker to start with data log files obtained from somewhere else. I've tested the `DumpLogSegments` tool with various versions of Kafka from 0.9 all the way up to 2.4.